# Spring MVC e o UTF-8

Tags: java, java-ee, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Estou fazendo uso do Spring MVC em um projeto, executando em servidor Glassfish e tendo problemas em exibir textos nas páginas JSP que contenham caracteres especiais, como acentos. Já tentei colocar o charset nas páginas HTML via HTML, HTML5 e até via tag JSP, mas não adiantou. Minha conexão com o banco está confirmadamente fazendo uso de UTF-8 e não sei mais o que falta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirme se você está usando o charset no HTML corretamente:

HTML 4

```
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />
```

HTML 5

```
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
```

JSP

```
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

Já que está usando o Spring MVC, é importante registrar um filter que faça encoding para UTF-8. Então, registre no seu arquivo `web.xml` o `CharacterEncodingFilter` e o configure para trabalhar com o UTF-8.

```
<filter>  
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>  
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>  
    <init-param>  
       <param-name>encoding</param-name>  
       <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>  
    </init-param>  
    <init-param>  
       <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>  
       <param-value>true</param-value>  
    </init-param>  
</filter>  
<filter-mapping>  
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>  
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

De uma olhada na configuração do GlassFish também, para ver se lá está ok, no glassfish-web.xml, veja se lá está também com o UTF-8:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app>
    <jsp-config>
    </jsp-config>
    <parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8" />
</glassfish-web-app>
```